# Code by Zapier to loop through an array of objects, pulling out one value per object and then average those values

Tags: javascript, webhooks, zapier

Using JavaScript for Zapier, I am trying to calculate the average value of a property from an array of object.

Here is one of the objects...

```js
{
    "code": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "28737",
            "owner": "1",
            "date": "1581945706",
            "dla": "0",
            "dlm": "1582551517",
            "system_source": "3",
            "source_location": null,
            "ip_addy": null,
            "ip_addy_display": null,
            "import_id": "0",
            "contact_cat": "*/*",
            "bulk_mail": "1",
            "bulk_sms": "0",
            "bindex": "76",
            "f1849": "9898983",
            "f1850": "Foundation Course 2: Lecture 1 QUIZ",
            "f1851": "0",
            "f1853": "John Doe",
            "f1854": "TRUE",
            "f1855": "93",    // <= calculate average for this property
            "f1859": "292",
            "f1862": "0",
            "f1867": "Kajabi",
            "f1868": "0",
            "unique_id": "7WB77PT"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I need to pull out the value for the property named `f1855` for each object, then calculate the average and return that value via POST.

I don't think this is hard to do with JavaScript but I am not used to the rules and limits of Zapier.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Seeing the edited version of your post, I am now not sure if your input data is the `data` array inside the example or it is an array of those objects.  If the second, then I don't know if you want an average for each object's `data` prop. or something else.  But the code below could be part of the solution in either case.

---

I don't know anything about Zapier, but the JavaScript part could look something like this:

```
const inputData = //your array of objects
const reducer = (sum, theObject) => sum + parseFloat(theObject.f1855)
const sumF1855 = inputData.reduce(reducer, 0)
const avgF1855 = sumF1855 / inputData.length
```

This code does not handle error conditions (like if on of the objects were missing the f1855 property or divide by zero if inputData were empty).  Hopefully it gives you an idea to get started.

Comment: there are 50 objects in the actual inputData array, so I am trying to gather that key's value for each object in the array, which are numerical and get the average and send back to Ontraport.

Comment: does "inputData array" refer to `inputData.data` or `[inputData1, inputData2, ..]`?  Trying to get clear on the semantics here.  My answer would work pretty easily for the first case and would need to be extended to handle the second.

Comment: Sorry to be confusing, what I mean is there is a response from my first step in Zapier, it is a json formatted array of objects containing key/value pairs. I believe its actual name is data.

Comment: {
    "code": 0,
    "data": [
        { //first object starts here

Comment: The error i get when trying to use your code from above is TypeError: inputData.reduce is not a function

Comment: Just to be super clear,  you will have to modify the code to run in your specific environment--please don't take what I have posted directly!  For your specific error, you need to modify the right side of the equal sign to point to the `data` property in your previous comment.  I left nothing but a comment after the `=` sign as a signal that you need to complete that section of the code (it will definitely _not_ work until you sort that out).